# how to draw a dashed curved line to a point in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I draw a dashed curved line to a x,y point in as3? Basically I'm creating a game where you have a turret, and I want the arc the turret would fire a projectile along to be displayed as a dashed/dotted line along the arc to wherever the mouse x,y is. Ideally it would use the drawing API, rather than using any bitmap manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it's not natively supported. You'll have to look for a library that does this, or write your own. Writing your own would involve a bit of maths, so a 3rd party library may be easier.

Comment: [degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) would be such a library.